# Pass class member function address to another member in initialization list

Tags: c++

Suppose that I have a class that accepts a function pointer in its constructor like this:

```
class IOControl
{
public:
    IOControl(void (*callback)(void));
};
```

And I have another class that I want to pass a non-static member address of it to above class constructor:

```
class Core
{
    public:
        Core();
    
    private:
        void some_callback();
        IOControl io;

};


Core::Core(): io(&Core::some_callback)
{

}
```

But I get this error:

> no matching function for call to 'IOControl::IOControl(void
> (Core::*)())'

If I make both `io` and `some_callback` as static it would work fine but as a non-static member, I get the above error.

Also using `Core::Core(): io(&(this->some_callback))` or `Core::Core(): io(&some_callback)` give me `ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function...` error.

Comment: pointers to free functions are not pointers to member functions.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Do you mean `some_callback` is a free function?

Comment: yes. Member function pointers are something entirely different, because they need an object to be called

Comment: the error message already tells you, the parameter you try to pass is of type `void (Core::*)()` thats a member function pointer, but the constructor takes a `void (*)(void)` thats a pointer to free function

Comment: @idclev463035818 So how can I define IO class to accept any member function pointer from any class? Is this possible?

Comment: What do you want to do with pointers to methods of arbitrary type? `template <typename T>  IOControl(T t);` would work, but remember: You need an object to call the method. Maybe open a new question